# Compiler unable to resolve type from shared 'header' file

Tags: f#

**In Common.fs:**

```
namespace Bug
module Common =
    type SourceEntity = {
        id : int
        link : string
    }
    type ReleaseEntity = {
        id : int
        notes : string
    }
```

**In Release.fs**

```
namespace Bug
open System
open Common
module Release =
    let cache = new Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, ReleaseEntity>()
    let AddToCache(entity) =
        cache.Add(entity.id, entity)
        ()
    let AddRec() =
        let entity : ReleaseEntity = {
            id = 1
            notes = "Notes"
        }
        AddToCache(entity)
```

**In Source.fs**

```
namespace Bug
open System
open Common
module Source =
    let Cache = new Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, SourceEntity>()
    let AddToCache(entity) =
        Cache.Add(entity.id, entity) <<=== E R R O R
        ()
    let AddRec() =
        let ent : SourceEntity = {
            id = 1
            releases = "Releases"
        }
        AddToCache(ent)  <<=== E R R O R
```

Files included in above order in the Visual Studio project.

Error reported in Source.fs:
Error   FS0001  This expression was expected to have type
    'SourceEntity'
but here has type
    'ReleaseEntity'

If the order of the two types in Common.fs are reversed, the error is reported in Release.fs where expected type is ReleaseEntity but has type SourceEntity.

Any ideas why this error is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a clash (and shadowing) of record field names.

When you write `entity.id` in the body of `Bug.Source.AddToCache`, the compiler uses the fact that you're accessing the `.id` field to infer the type of `entity`. Which records have a field named `id`? Well, those two records do, but the compiler has to pick one. How? Easy: the last one takes precedence. This is called "shadowing".

In order to disambiguate the choice, just add a type annotation:

```
let AddToCache(entity) = 
    Cache.Add(entity.id, entity)
    ()
```

---

Wait, but why doesn't the compiler use the type of `Cache.Add` to infer the type of `entity`?

Well, this is just a limitation (or a feature?) of F#. The compilation is single-pass, type interference proceeds top down, left to right, without doublebacks. This allows the compiler to be very fast and very predictable (looking at you, Haskell).

But in this case it means that by the time the compiler sees that `entity` is used as parameter in `Cache.Add`, it has already decided what its type must be.

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't fully appreciate that the compiler context was being carried in its entirety despite going to a new file and a new module.

Answer (score 1):

When you get a type error, try to think about how the compiler came to infer that particular type.

Here:

```
let AddToCache(entity) =
    cache.Add(entity.id, entity)
    ()
```

Could the compiler know which type has would have an `id` field in `entity`?
If you had typed in

```
let entity = { id = 1; link  = "" }
```

the compiler would infer that this is `SourceEntity` because only `SourceEntity` has those particular record fields. In `cache.Add(entity.id, entity)`, the compiler has no other constraints to go by, other than it has to have an `id` field, so it picks the last matching type - and that is why you get the error.

If you refactor the common id field to

```
namespace Bug
module Common =
    type SourceEntity = {
        source_id : int
        link : string
    }
    type ReleaseEntity = {
        release_id : int
        notes : string
    }
```

you will find that the error disappears.

**Solutions**

All of the solutions involve constraining it to a known type.

The simplest is to add a type annotation:

```
let AddToCache(entity: SourceEntity) =
```

Another is to deconstruct it explicitly:

```
let { SourceEntity.id = id } = entity
Cache.Add(id, entity)
```

Another is to coerce the type - this isn't relevant here, but it may come to be useful down the road:

```
Cache.Add((entity :> SourceEntity).id, entity)
```

I'd recommend [this article](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/type-inference/) from F# for fun and profit on type inference for a nice explanation of the process.

**P.S.**

You actually only needed that one type annotation. 
The rest can be inferred :)

```
module Source =
    let Cache = new Collections.Generic.Dictionary<_, _>()
    let AddToCache (entity: SourceEntity) =
        Cache.Add(entity.id, entity) 
        ()
    let AddRec () =
        let ent = {
            id = 1
            link = ""
        }
        AddToCache(ent)
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply.  Recursive intermodule dependencies are an issue I am still struggling with - may need to reorganize common code in class and use inheritance - something I wanted to avoid.

Comment: If there's nothing else, you could close the question.